# Automatically Interaction between MVC and R projects in visual studio 2017

Tags: r, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have mvc project and R project under same solution, I want to run mvc first display it on browser then send some arguments to script.R in R project then run R project and refreshing mvc based on results of R project

Currently I can execute Script.r and the results saved as html then I run mvc and html results from R are displayed on the browser.
 I need to make it automatically.

My code is like this code https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar6hTIP_Ln58h6JtpQQ3yt3JjIsIFg

**Controller code**

```
using WebApplication1.Infrastructure;
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RScript.Run("HeatMap", 1997);
        RScript.Run("HeatMap", 1998);
        return View();
    }
```

**Rscript class code**

```
public static class RScript
{
    public static bool Run(string filename, int year = 0)
    {
        var rCodeFilePath = $"C:\\Users\\COMNET\\source\\repos\\Test\\RProject1\\RProject1\\{filename}.R";
        if (year != 0)
            rCodeFilePath = $"{rCodeFilePath} {year}";

        var rScriptExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe";

        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = rScriptExecutablePath,
                WorkingDirectory = 
         Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath),
                Arguments = rCodeFilePath,
                RedirectStandardInput = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };


            using (var proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = info;
                proc.Start();
                proc.Close();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return false;
            throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);

        }
    }
}
```

**R script code**

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
cn <- odbcConnect('', uid = '', pwd = '')
view <- ifelse(args[1] == 1998, 'vwR1TranValuebyCountryCategoty98', 'vwR1TranValuebyCountryCategoty97')
qtyNatCat <- sqlFetch(cn, view)
odbcClose(cn)
q <- ggplot(qtyNatCat, aes(x = Category, y = Country, fill = TransValue))
q <- q + geomtile()
q <- q + geomraster()
q <- q + scalefillgradient(low = "#c00000", high = "#00c000", na.value = "white")
q <- q + xlab('') + ylab('')
q <- q + theme(axis.text.x = elementtext(angle = 10, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
q <- q + labs(fill = "Qty\nper\nTran")
wd <- getwd()
imagedir <- paste("C:\\Users\\COMNET\\Downloads\\net to the power of r\\NorthwindDashboard\\NorthwindDashboard\\Content\\html\\", sep = "")
setwd(imagedir)
filename <- ifelse(args[1] == 1998, 'heatmap98.png', 'heatmap97.png')
if (file.exists(filename))
    file.remove(filename)
ggsave(q, file = filename, width = 9, height = 4)
setwd(wd)
```